# swig error in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: shared-library

For some reason **swig** on my computer is not configured correctly.
It gives this output on checking version:

```
$ swig --version

swig: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

whereas on reinstalling it the following output is generated:

```
piyush@piyush-HP:~/test$ sudo apt-get install swig
[sudo] password for piyush: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
swig is already the newest version (3.0.8-0ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

any suggestions for how to fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install` and see if that helps, look slike there might be an issue with a dependency.

Comment: cross-posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421257/swig-error-in-ubuntu-16-04